# Product image in gmap4rails infowindow with cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, infowindow, gmaps4rails, cloudinary

I want to display my product image in a marker infowindow, but I get a broken link error:

> qmxjai8cmuuve5mnpf4y.jpg:1
>   GET localhost:3000/v1503135294/qmxjai8cmuuve5mnpf4y.jpg 404 (Not Found)

I don't know how to include a cloudinary link in my infowindow.

My infowindow:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow(bien)
        "
        <div class='col-xs-6'>
          <a href='#{user_path(product.user)}', class='btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-sm'>Accéder au profil</a>
        </div>
        <img src=\"#{product.user.photo.path}\" style='width: 200px; height: auto; margin: 10px; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;'>
        "
      end
```

How I display it in my view:

```
<%= cl_image_tag user.photo.path, height: 100, width: 200 %>
```

Comment: Please share the full error message you've got.

Comment: I dont got error message but the error image icon and when i display the path of my image its the good link @RoeeBen-Ari

Comment: Try changing it to   `<img src="#{product.user.photo.path}" style='width: 200px; height: auto; margin: 10px; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;'>`

Comment: Check for the error message in your Browser's debugger under 'Network' --> 'Response Headers'.

Comment: My error message is "qmxjai8cmuuve5mnpf4y.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:3000/v1503135294/qmxjai8cmuuve5mnpf4y.jpg 404 (Not Found)" @RoeeBen-Ari

Comment: In which folder you have that image?

Comment: The image is on Cloudinary not in local

Comment: The first parameter for `cl_image_tag` should be the image's public ID and not a path. In your case it should be - 'qmxjai8cmuuve5mnpf4y'. See doc [here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_manipulation#display_images).

Comment: I included that specific error message in your question.